# If every nbd of $x$ also contains $y$, does there exist a path connecting $x$ and $y$?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

If $x,y \in X$ are two points in a topological space, and every neighborhood of $x$ also contains $y$, are $x$ and $y$ connected by a path?

I don't really know how or where to start. If $\{ U_i\}_{i \in I}$ are the described open sets, doesn't the constant sequence $(x)_{i \in I}$ converge to $y$? A sequence converges if and only if it is eventually constant, and here it is always constant. But isn't it necessary for $I$ to be infinite? In any case, I can't translate this into paths. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @JohnHughes Completely right. I was sloppy. Changing it.

Comment: It is not generally true that a sequence converges if and only if it is eventually constant. One direction is true, the other one isn't: consider $x_n=1/n$ in the real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two observations that may help.

1. Consider the two-point subspace $A=\{x,y\}$ of $X$. What are the possible subspace topologies that $A$ can inherit?
2. You can define paths in finite spaces. For example, if $B=\{x,y,z\}$ is a space with topology $\{B,\{x\},\{z\},\{x,z\},\emptyset\}$, the function $p:[0,1]\to B$, $p([0,1/2))=x$, $p(\{1/2\})=y$, $p((1/2,1])=z$ is a path since it satisfies the definition of continuity.

Comment: Two point x,y Sierpinski space with open x is an example of a path from x to y.  How about other not T1 spaces?  Is there always a path from x to y?

Comment: The Sierpinski space is a path connected space. Of course, not all non-$T_1$ spaces are path connected. However, if $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$ in any space, then there is a path from $x$ to $y$ in $X$. This is because the subspace $\{x,y\}$ is either indiscrete or the Sierpinski space (as suggested in the hints).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It's not a counterexample, but it'll at least get you thinking in the right direction....take a look at the "[line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold)" to see why your convergence argument isn't valid. (Well...it's valid...but the limit you get is $x$ rather than $y$.)

Note: a sequence won't help anyhow, because you need to build a *path*, not just a sequence of points. Otherwise the points $0$ and $1$ in $\Bbb Q$ would be "connected".

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that intervals are path-connected, whereas an arbitrary open set in an arbitrary topology might not be. I can't assume that there is some point $p_1$ that can be connected by a path to $y$, and then some other point $p_2$ connected to $p_1$ and so on, until I reach $x$. Do you have any comment on that?

Comment: Yes, that *is* the problem. You should probably work, alternately, on trying to prove and to disprove the claim. And perhaps you should look at the line with two origins again. And again.

Comment: Do I need to add the assumption that the neighborhoods be path connected?

Comment: If you're trying to answer a problem in a textbook, you should not add any hypotheses that are not stated in the problem. If you're trying to prove a theorem so that you can make some use of it, you should add only the hypotheses that you need and no others. Beyond that, I can't really give you an answer.

Comment: @JohnHughes.  Why?  That space is T1 and {x} is not closed.  Thus x is not in that space.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Why *what*?  I really don't understand anything you just wrote. Does "that space" refer to the line with two origins? If so, what does "x" mean here? One of the two origins? That seems unlikely, since clearly both origins ARE in the line with two origins. The problem statement says nothing about T1 spaces, so the fact that some space is T1 shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @JohnHughes.  The two origin line is T1.  The space under consideration containing x and y has a point that not closed.  Whence the two 0 line is not an example nor a counter example.

Comment: I did not say it was a counterexample (indeed, I said it was *not*). But looking at it and thinking about it might prove fruitful.